# Названия месяцев

Tags: этимология

В украинском языке сохранились общеславянские названия месяцев. Как правило, названия там понятные. Например, серпень (август) - время, когда серпом собирают зерновые, листопад (ноябрь) - все понятно, травень (май) - тоже все понятно. И только два названия вызываются затруднения: червень (июнь) и вересень (сентябрь). От каких славянских слов они произошли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Червень — Июнь или Июль, червоный. По одной из версий, этот месяц получил название от червецов, чьи личинки появляются в это время, из которых изготавливали красную краску; по другой версии, это личинки пчёл; по третьей версии - из-за того, что в это время появляются красные ягоды и цветы. 
Месяц сентябрь -  вересень , от названия растения вереска, которое цветет в летне-осенний период.

Answer (score 1):

"Червецы" - это насекомое кошениль, из которого получали кармин - наиболее распространённую красную краску. Хотя есть подозрение, что эта этимология может быть ошибочна. Кошениль - насекомое обитающее далеко не повсеместно, да и хозяйственное значение его не столь велико. Скорее всего общеславянкое "червоны" относится к самому месяцу, погоде, яркому солнцу. Во всех известных мне языках "червень" - июнь, никак не июль. Июль - "липень".
~ ~ ~
Шоб вивчити назви 12 украинських мiсяцiв, треба в **серпнi** пiд **вересень** взяти гарну дiвчину, повести пiд **березень**, покласти на **травень**, впереться ногами в **липень** , взять однiею рукою за **грудень**, а iншою за **жовтень**, всунути свий **лютий червень** в iй **квiтень** i робити такой **сiчень**, щоб почався **листопад**! 
©Сперто с инета, но понравилось.

Comment: На многих сайтах просто написано, что червень - это июнь или июль, а вот здесь http://nfor.org/stati/znanija/slavjanskii-jazycheskii-kalendar-mesjaceslov.html есть подробная таблица названия всех месяцев во всех славянских языках, и разные варианты названий. Так, июнь - не только червень, но и изок, кресень, а июль - не только липень, но и червень (как месяц. в котором больше всего солнечных дней), и грозник.

Comment: Сайт не производит впечатления адкуватного. Там половина названий относится к двум месяцам на основании "сноса" на 13 дней в сявязи с разницей юлианской и григорианской эр. Это все равно, что требовать называть ноябрь октябрём, а март - февралём потому только, что октябрьская и февральская революции произошли в ноябре и марте по новому стилю.
Других источников не знаю.

Comment: У ДАля: МЕСЯЦ м. ...  июнь (народн. голодай, ау, пусто в закромах; стар. червень, изок); июль (народн. сенозарник, страдник, грозник, макушка лета; стар. червень, липец)

Comment: Тоже не очень понятно, как два месяца могут носить одно названия.
ну да ладно. Я-то в любом случае говорил о названиях *в славянских языках*. А не у Даля. К свидетельствам которого, кстати, надо относиться с большой осторожностью.